# Creating json from dataframe with groupby and multiple columns to list

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a little issue reverting the flattening of a pandas dataframe after operations have been performed on it. So, initially, the dataframe has this structure:

```
                                   id  \
0    168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   
1    bb1945ad-ebe7-499a-98aa-3ad7301ad8cd   
2    02b5414b-229a-41c9-9e7e-319e148217ac   
3    13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1   
4    929a3367-be8d-45b6-a074-2dab522d9c9b   
..                                    ...   
182  158d5cc3-a067-421f-91d4-9debfe929f2f   
183  a4416149-4ebd-42fe-aa86-6e5d0e9fc4a0   
184  e3272663-6cc0-46ea-975e-23b0b5af4339   
185  5f1611ea-ae7b-428e-981f-27c72c341d13   
186  17ba4f2b-14d8-4b89-a227-84e9dfb36587   

                                               polygon  \
0    [{'x': 32.987843, 'y': 37.251873, 'floor': 0},...   
1    [{'x': 29.828306, 'y': 38.619965, 'floor': 0},...   
2    [{'x': 29.819393, 'y': 37.710873, 'floor': 0},...   
3    [{'x': 27.031515, 'y': 38.58253, 'floor': 0}, ...   
4    [{'x': 26.995865, 'y': 37.70018, 'floor': 0}, ...   
..                                                 ...   
182  [{'x': -10.445796, 'y': 6.1944127, 'floor': 0}...   
183  [{'x': -10.444014, 'y': 1.3263202, 'floor': 0}...   
184  [{'x': -2.167721, 'y': -7.1950703, 'floor': 0}...   
185  [{'x': 19.109201, 'y': 16.013615, 'floor': 0},...   
186  [{'x': 19.229523, 'y': 15.911119, 'floor': 0},...   

                                                 edges  
0    [{'id': 'ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3'...  
1    [{'id': 'e8fb3049-f4db-40ad-8b92-0046d07953a7'...  
2    [{'id': '30aca2d8-5639-4715-97b0-c401901b9262'...  
3    [{'id': 'df2bd88d-9861-41ee-a70f-0dd633c443c2'...  
4    [{'id': '47df1272-0a20-433d-829b-56260717a756'...  
..                                                 ...  
182  [{'id': '1b9983a4-51da-476c-8b8d-cf4bcf1fcae1'...  
183  [{'id': '20368ff0-8010-48cf-b56b-19bdfcaf5254'...  
184  [{'id': 'b0408a66-9b3a-4f73-9adf-9410f060cd21'...  
185  [{'id': '927ab124-4e15-4181-a780-e40a9dca2d6f'...  
186  [{'id': 'a817c411-6bf3-4068-9484-9dd6625d3dae'...  

[187 rows x 3 columns]
```

As you can see, the columns ´´´polygon`and`edges``` consists of lists of positions and floors. Now, unfortunately, these positions needed to be transformed (rotated around a fixed point). I therefore unnested the entire dataframe (flattened it), did my transformation and ended up with a dataframe of the type:

```
id  polygon.x  polygon.y  \
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   
0      0  168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3   9.942374   48.75499   

   polygon.floor                              edges.id  edges.shelfLength  \
0              0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3                NaN   
0              0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7                NaN   
0              0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982                NaN   
0              0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d                NaN   
0              0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3                NaN   
0              0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7                NaN   
0              0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982                NaN   
0              0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d                NaN   
0              0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3                NaN   
0              0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7                NaN   
0              0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982                NaN   
0              0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d                NaN   
0              0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3                NaN   
0              0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7                NaN   
0              0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982                NaN   
0              0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d                NaN   
0              0  ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3                NaN   
0              0  d2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7                NaN   
0              0  c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982                NaN   
0              0  ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d                NaN   

   edges.linkable  
0           False  
0           False  
0           False  
0            True  
0           False  
0           False  
0           False  
0            True  
0           False  
0           False  
0           False  
0            True  
0           False  
0           False  
0           False  
0            True  
0           False  
0           False  
0           False  
0            True
```

Note that the `id` is the same for "many rows" but that the number of unique `id` is the same as in the original dataframe.

Now, I want to revert the flattening and make the resulting dataframe into a json file, meaning that I want the columns `polygon.x, polygon.y, polygon.floor` and `edges.id,  edges.linkable` to be in the form `polygon` and `edges` as in the original dataframe AND to write in to a json string of the type:

```
[{'id': '168bb0ea-3748-42ad-84c3-aa20e62c73b3',
  'polygon': [{'x': 32.987843, 'y': 37.251873, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 33.567165, 'y': 37.251873, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 33.567165, 'y': 44.86328, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 32.987843, 'y': 44.86328, 'floor': 0}],
  'edges': [{'id': 'ac249205-3b06-42b3-b6fb-85763fdfced3',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': 'd2155659-56c0-4520-9330-f9b61a097ca7',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': 'c4582dd7-2b7b-4453-8374-c2e3da335982',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': 'ab68fa67-2f46-49cf-b319-8454d5820f9d',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': True}]},
 {'id': 'bb1945ad-ebe7-499a-98aa-3ad7301ad8cd',
  'polygon': [{'x': 29.828306, 'y': 38.619965, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 31.058252, 'y': 38.619965, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 31.058252, 'y': 44.41319, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 29.828306, 'y': 44.41319, 'floor': 0}],
  'edges': [{'id': 'e8fb3049-f4db-40ad-8b92-0046d07953a7',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': '5207ea5e-79ee-4939-9d66-48834f9d281a',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': True},
   {'id': 'b26e0782-c8b5-46e2-afff-814941bec001',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': 'a6142875-99a1-4139-b074-a23a6e47eca6',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': True}]},
 {'id': '02b5414b-229a-41c9-9e7e-319e148217ac',
  'polygon': [{'x': 29.819393, 'y': 37.710873, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 31.156292, 'y': 37.710873, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 31.156292, 'y': 38.584312, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 29.819393, 'y': 38.584312, 'floor': 0}],
  'edges': [{'id': '30aca2d8-5639-4715-97b0-c401901b9262',
    'shelfLength': 1.2,
    'linkable': True},
   {'id': '93d82a40-e7e9-4d4e-aa0b-8d2ad540b3e0',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': '13a4846f-667f-4c9f-8cdb-efa447eed406',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': '87dda457-3327-484c-8cdc-1cd397e3c1af',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False}]},
 {'id': '13e70e96-2554-49c5-9c2e-4df1beb8efb1',
  'polygon': [{'x': 27.031515, 'y': 38.58253, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 28.261461, 'y': 38.58253, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 28.261461, 'y': 44.37576, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 27.031515, 'y': 44.37576, 'floor': 0}],
  'edges': [{'id': 'df2bd88d-9861-41ee-a70f-0dd633c443c2',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': 'e49832f7-af6b-4da3-b2c2-8a66cb16cc39',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': True},
   {'id': 'c02da2b8-1df4-440e-926c-2a2306cd0318',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': '66689e8c-fd24-4eb1-b46c-b4371d354aff',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': True}]},
 {'id': '929a3367-be8d-45b6-a074-2dab522d9c9b',
  'polygon': [{'x': 26.995865, 'y': 37.70018, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 28.332764, 'y': 37.70018, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 28.332764, 'y': 38.57362, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 26.995865, 'y': 38.57362, 'floor': 0}],
  'edges': [{'id': '47df1272-0a20-433d-829b-56260717a756',
    'shelfLength': 1.2,
    'linkable': True},
   {'id': '342ca2ed-fe58-44ab-8efc-94409d3fd396',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': '390fab2d-a0d0-4ea2-9285-c5dc25cf7a6f',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': 'd1951bea-932b-4f92-913b-e04c0b7aa963',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False}]},
 {'id': '5e36fbc5-b5d4-4f32-9f53-d713e389b13d',
  'polygon': [{'x': 19.034254, 'y': 45.92993, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 31.38868, 'y': 45.92993, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 31.38868, 'y': 46.517555, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 19.034254, 'y': 46.517555, 'floor': 0}],
  'edges': [{'id': '8395d1d1-b676-43a0-92dd-e4038df9549c',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': True},
   {'id': '7741f927-5cfe-4c74-837d-ee73e9b5be17',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': '415868a6-7ad4-4a81-b94e-0ae29d5b4699',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False},
   {'id': '55a92ce2-e9cf-4094-9c0d-bfd023f8a961',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False}]},
 {'id': '6ea960d1-30f7-47e8-bdb4-2eb4d936d254',
  'polygon': [
{'x': 21.453197, 'y': 38.58206, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 22.683144, 'y': 38.58206, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 22.683144, 'y': 44.375294, 'floor': 0},
   {'x': 21.453197, 'y': 44.375294, 'floor': 0}],
  'edges': [{'id': 'bfd5edc8-c2be-4072-8675-ae9045bcac26',
    'shelfLength': None,
    'linkable': False}]}]
```

Now, I tried:

```
df1 = geostoreObstaclesdf.groupby(['id'])['polygon.x','polygon.y','polygon.floor'].agg(list).reset_index()
```

but it does not return what I expected.

I would be very grateful for any ideas on how I could go about doing this.